# Passing data between different apps on a single device

Tags: ios

I'm designing a game and I'm still pretty much in the planning phase for the most part. I'm considering a pretty cool feature, but I'm not sure if it will be doable yet. What i have in mind is: would it be possible to access a game save from one game using a second game.
Clearler explanation: I release game A, user plays through game A and collects some game items along the way (weapons, equipment, whatever). Then later, I release game B, which can be considered a continuation of game A (think DLC terms). Game B can be played from scratch, its a standalone release, but I'd like to offer players an option to transfer their character progression from the previous one. Would I have an option to do that?

Is it for instance possible to create a save file on a device in some neutral directory (not linked to a specific app), so that different apps can all reference the same file on the device?

Comment: It's almost certainly possible somehow. Why not try to put something together and ask specific questions when you have an approach that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the options:

- App A and App B could launch each other using URL custom scheme launching with the data to pass between them appended to the end of the URL
- They can share data using the keychain
- They can share data using a custom pasteboard
- Treat the data as a document and share via UIDocumentInteractionController
- They can share data using UIActivityViewController
- They share data indirectly using a server / cloud

Comment: @mr-h When you say that they can share data using the keychain, does this imply that any app can look at the contents of my keychain? Or is there some setup I need to do beforehand? My question is unrelated to OP's, but I'm storing some passwords in the keychain and if other apps can access them, then I have a problem...

Comment: You don't have a problem - the keychain is intended to be secure and not accessable by other apps, however you can share data within the keychain between *your* apps  provided they have a common app ID prefix.

Comment: i.e. com.yourcompany.appA and com.yourcompany.appB can share the keychain but com.somebodyelsescompany.appC can't

Comment: There is nothing deprecated about using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. It is still a perfectly valid option. `UIActivityViewController` is not the proper way to share a single document with another app.

Comment: @rmaddy, you're correct regarding UIDocumentInteractionController, I misread something.